# MYSQL - Determine tables primary key in order

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a query which gives me the primary key of all tables from a database, at the same order that it was created, for example:

CREATE TABLE `a_antennaport`

...

PRIMARY KEY (`dateday`,`neid`,`cn`,`srn`,`sn`,`pn`)

I need as output the fields in the same order:
`dateday`,`neid`,`cn`,`srn`,`sn`,`pn`

I already tried:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = schema()
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='PRIMARY'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query should work already (in fact, it does. Tested, to be sure). Only thing you can improve to make sure, that the columns are in the right order, is to order by the ordinal position in the group_concat().

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION), TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = schema()
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='PRIMARY'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```